# Malloc/free misunderstanding

Tags: c

I have programm crash when freeing last `struct bbb` variable in kill procedure. But why why? Suppose problem somewhere in `free`.

```
struct bbb
{
    struct bbb * h;
    char a [256];
    int i;
};



void kill(struct bbb * value)
{
    if (value!=NULL)
    {

    kill(value->h);

    printf("killing %s\n", value->a);
    free(value);
    printf("killed\n");
    value=NULL;
    }
}

void ins(struct bbb * b, struct bbb * a )
{
    b->h= malloc(sizeof(struct bbb ) );
    b->h[0]=*a;
}

int main(void) {

    struct bbb a;
    struct bbb b;
    struct bbb c;
    //ss=s;
    sprintf(a.a,"aaa" );
    sprintf(b.a,"bbb" );
    sprintf(c.a,"ccc" );

    ins(&b,&c);
    ins(&a,&b);

    kill(&a);

    //printf("a.a=%s\n",a.a);





    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
killing ccc
killed
killing bbb
killed
killing aaa
*** glibc detected *** /home/aaa/workspace_train/SmallTest/Debug/SmallTest: double free or corruption (out): 0x00007ffff0fe3d20 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7eb96)[0x7fa77ec56b96]
/home/gedas/workspace_train/SmallTest/Debug/SmallTest(kill+0x48)[0x400e15]
/home/gedas/workspace_train/SmallTest/Debug/SmallTest[0x400ef9]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7fa77ebf976d]
```

Comment: Compile with `-g`. It will make your life better.

Comment: *In Clippy's voice* -Did you mean `kill(a.h);`?

Answer (score 7):

You allocated `a` on the stack, and then try to `free` its address. You can call free only on pointers which you got by malloc or similar functions.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there's no need for that malloc, here's my solution:

```
struct bbb
{
    struct bbb * h;
    char name [256];
    int i;
};



void _kill(struct bbb * value)
{
    if (value!=NULL)
    {
        _kill(value->h);
        printf("killing %s\n", value->name);
        value->h=NULL;
        value=NULL;

        printf("killed\n");
    }
}

void ins(struct bbb * b, struct bbb * a )
{
//    b->h= malloc(sizeof(struct bbb *) );
    b->h= a;
}

int main(void) {

    struct bbb a;
    struct bbb b;
    struct bbb c;
    //ss=s;
    sprintf(a.name,"aaa" );
    sprintf(b.name,"bbb" );
    sprintf(c.name,"ccc" );

    ins(&b,&c);
    ins(&a,&b);

    _kill(&a);
    //printf("a.a=%s\n",a.a);


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```